# Check setup/hold time violations dynamically in an instantiated Verilog module (Yosys/CVC)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a SystemVerilog testbench tb_top that instantiates a given Verilog module top. The code in top is effectively unknown to me (it comes from multiple sources), but I know the ports include a 100 Hz clock (called hundo in this post), 21 inputs and 75 outputs.

I use CVC to simulate the testbench with the Verilog module, and Yosys to perform synthesis. My goal is to introduce timing checks on any potential flip flops in the Verilog module after synthesis, and throw warnings if they occur.

I know of the $setup/$hold methods and that they work in SystemVerilog and in CVC simulation. However, I can't figure out a way to dynamically apply those methods to every flip flop in the top module. An example of a setup time violation:

```
module top (hundo, reset, [rest of inputs], ex_output, [rest of outputs]);
  // ... port declarations ...

  reg ex_out;
  always @(posedge hundo, posedge reset)
    if (reset)
      ex_out <= 0;
    else
      ex_out <= hundo;

  assign ex_output = ex_out;
endmodule
```

And this would be the testbench in which I would specify the setup violation:

```
module tb_top ();
  // ... tb_port declarations ...
  // ... generate clock on tb_hundo ...

specify 
      specparam tsetup = 1;
      $setup(tb_ex_output, posedge tb_hundo, tsetup);
endspecify

top inst (.hundo (tb_hundo), ...);

endmodule
```

In CVC simulation, that should throw a warning. However, it doesn't work. Is there any way to make it recognize timing violations on the flip flops inside the module (regardless of whether the flip flop is connected to a port output)?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to apply the timing constraints on every flop. When you are running gate level simulations, you should have a vendor gate level library. That has the setup and hold timing checks included.

The normal procedure is that a tool extracts the timing from the synthesized netlist and produces an "SDF" (Standard Delay Format) file. You then run gate level simulations in which you read and apply the SDF file. SDF annotation is only possible and only makes sense if the gate level netlist has timing constructs, not only for the gates but also for all interconnects.